# CMake How to set src root directory so that always finding header files from root directory instead of relative path?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have an issue about including header file.

**Error Message**

```
In file included from /path/to/src/main.cpp:1:
/path/to/src/dirA/testA.h:1:10: fatal error: 'common/util.h' file not found
#include "common/util.h"
```

**directory**

```
├── dirA
│   └── testA.h
├── common
│   └── util.h
└── main.cpp
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "dirA/testA.h"

int main()
{}
```

**testA.h**

```
#include "common/util.h" // <--- Here is the error point
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_definitions("-std=c++11") 

add_executable(main
  main.cpp
)
```

I found that the following way is fine but I don't want to think the file path relation.

```
#include "../common/util.h"
```

---

Update 1

Thanks to Mark Farrugia's answer, the build error was solved. However, I like "common/util.h" better than "util.h" since the path is easy to understand. And it might to avoid duplicated definitions.

**testA.h**

```
#include "util.h"
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_definitions("-std=c++11") 

include_directories("common")

add_executable(main
  main.cpp
)
```

Comment: I have edited my response to answer your new question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CMake's `include_directories` command.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html

The following will include all files in the `common` directory project-wide:

```
include_directories(common);
```

Use this as:

```
#include <util.h>
```

Or if you want to use the folder in the `#include` directive:

```
include_directories(.)
```

This way you can do the following:

```
#include <common/util.h>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

While `include_directories` will work here, unless you are stuck with a very old (older than 2.8.10) CMake version, [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/target_include_directories.html) should be the preferred command for solving this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

add_executable(main
    main.cpp
)
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC .)
set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

In newer CMake versions you should always prefer the `target_*` form of the commands if available. This is of particular significance for larger projects, where managing the build purely based on the physical layout of the source files (which is what the old, directory-based commands force you to do), can be quite difficult. The new commands also offer a couple of additional features, like inheriting properties transitively to dependent targets, that can come in very handy for more complex builds.

If you are at liberty to use CMake 3.1 or higher, you can also replace the explicit setting of the `std=c++11` compile flag with the more portable code above.

Comment: Thanks. My cmake is v3.8.2. I will look into what you mentioned.